# While using hashHistory in react, in createhashHistory current path not getting and it's redirecting to the login page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I am using react scripts to render my view in my MVC application.
I am facing issues with browser history, when I refresh the page it is showing error 404. I got a solution for it. I used hashHistory instead of browserHistory. Now page is refreshing and showing url like http://localhost:1647/#/services. When I click on link in this page, in respose I open a new page ,which is opening and showing data ; but on existing page it is going to the login page instead of remaining in current page where the link is shown.I checked in console in hashHistory, the encoded path getting blank(/).

(Initially it was working fine when we were using browserhistory, it was showing the calling page itself, when I open a new page on clicking the link. But while refreshing ,it was showing 404 error. To resolve this issue I used hashhistory. Now the calling page is redirecting to login, instead of staying in current page. How to resolve it?)

following is the react script I used to open new window while clicking on link in services page.

service.js

```
 UrlHandler(event, path) {
        debugger;
        let userName = this.state.username;
        let Path = path;

        fetch("Home/GenerateKey", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                userid: userName,
                url: path
            })

        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json() // << This is the problem
            }).then(responsedata => {
                debugger;
                console.log(responsedata)
                window.open(responsedata, "_blank");
               // history.push("/services")
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                alert("error")
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
```

////////
router.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, HashRouter, Switch, hashHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './login';
import Services from './services';
import Billing from './billing';
import createHashHistory from '../history';

class Routers extends component {
    render() {
        return (

            <HashRouter history={createHashHistory}>
                <Switch>
                <div>
                     <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
                    <Route exact path="/billing" component={Billing} />
                </div>
                </Switch>
            </ HashRouter>

            )
    }
}

//<Route children={({ match }) => (<Link to={to}>{label}</Link>)} />


export default Routers;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.